# How I can use GPIO ports for raw serial and clock?

Tags: serial

I want to read some data out from a macronix `MX35LF1GE4AB` flash memory chip, but it uses RAW serial and does not mention some for of existing serial comminications (eg. UART, I^2C etc etc).

The chip's documentation is the following:
https://www.macronix.com/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/7770/MX35LF1GE4AB,%203V,%201Gb,%20v1.8.pdf

What I want to do is to use RAW serial IO and clock, so I can interface the chip in Low level. Is there a way to do so?

Also in order to provide clock and to read serial via software what pins I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the SPI interface. There are drivers etc available for this. You will find there are a lot of SPI memory chips on the market. It is generally much faster than I2C. Page 8 shows the pinout with the standard labels.